# Select most popular users given by likes, posts and comments

Tags: mysql, select

I have a forum and I would like to find the most popular users. The most popular users definded by the most likes on posts and comments and also defined by the most total posts and comments. A user with the **most likes** (order 1), **most posts** (order 2) and **most comments** (order 3) is the most popular. Same logic applies for the next (second) most popular user.

So I have 3 tables:

**posts table**

```
id      user_id     likes
1       1           0
2       1           0
3       1           0
4       1           0
5       1           0
6       1           1
7       1           0
8       2           0
9       2           2
10      2           0
11      2           0
12      3           0
13      3           0
14      4           0
15      4           10
```

**comments table**

```
id      user_id     likes
1       1           0
2       1           1
3       1           1
4       1           0
5       2           0
6       2           2
7       2           1
8       4           1
9       4           0
```

**users table**

```
id      name
1       John
2       Adam
3       Maggie
4       Steve
```

The likes column contains the likes given by other users on the respective post (row).
I tried:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.name,
    SUM(a.likes), SUM(b.likes), (SUM(a.likes) + SUM(b.likes)) as popular,
    COUNT(a.id) as mostp, COUNT(b.id) as mostc
    FROM posts as a, comments as b, users as c
    WHERE a.user_id=b.user_id AND a.user_id=c.id AND b.user_id=c.id
    GROUP BY a.user_id, b.user_id ORDER BY popular DESC, mostp DESC, mostc DESC
```

Obviously, this does not work, because if you test the query it gives more likes(sum) than expected.

Here is the live query
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/08900/3

Comment: Put your data (or a subset thereof) in a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com), so those of us without access to MySQL can help you.

Comment: can you post your desired output

Comment: The desired output would be the results extrapolated from SUM are exactly as in the tables. The wrong output (as is now) ends up with a cartesian product.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your query is with users that have more than one post and more than one comment, resulting in a cartesian product and producing the wrong sums.

The query below (example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c35f/8)) should work, since the subqueries already group by `user_id`:

```
SELECT
  u.name,
  COALESCE(p.likes,0) + COALESCE(c.likes,0) AS likes,
  COALESCE(p.cnt,0) AS post_count,
  COALESCE(c.cnt,0) AS comment_count
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt, SUM(likes) AS likes
  FROM posts
  GROUP BY user_id
) p ON ( p.user_id = u.id )
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt, SUM(likes) AS likes
  FROM comments
  GROUP BY user_id
) c ON ( c.user_id = u.id )
ORDER BY likes DESC, post_count DESC, comment_count DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
|   NAME | LIKES | POST_COUNT | COMMENT_COUNT |
-----------------------------------------------
|  Steve |    11 |          2 |             2 |
|   Adam |     5 |          4 |             3 |
|   John |     3 |          7 |             4 |
| Maggie |     0 |          2 |             0 |
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Even when new users are added into the users table with no posts or comments at all. Thanks you again for useful advice :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do this

```
SELECT
  u.id,
  u.name,
  (l.likes + r.likes) As TotalLikes,
  IFNULL(posts,0) AS TotalPosts,
  IFNULL(comments,0) AS TotalComments
FROM users AS u
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           user_id,
           IFNULL(SUM(likes),0) as likes,
           COUNT(likes) as posts
         FROM posts
         GROUP BY user_id) AS l
    on l.user_id = u.id
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT
           user_id,
           IFNULL(SUM(likes),0) as likes,
           COUNT(likes) AS comments
         FROM comments
         GROUP BY user_id) AS r
    on r.user_id = u.id
ORDER BY TotalLikes DESc
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/209a7/2)

Output

```
| ID |   NAME | TOTALLIKES | TOTALPOSTS | TOTALCOMMENTS |
---------------------------------------------------------
|  4 |  Steve |         11 |          2 |             2 |
|  2 |   Adam |          5 |          4 |             3 |
|  1 |   John |          3 |          7 |             4 |
|  3 | Maggie |          0 |          2 |             0 |
```

Comment: You will have to do separate `IFNULL`s for `l.like` and `r.like`, otherwise users who have only comments **or** posts will get `TotalLikes=0` even if they have likes.